# Animated gif in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I would like to add a gif image to my app. The app has to record audio in mp3 format. I would like to have a gif image for recording which would just flash or show loading gif when recording is started. Kind of indication for the user saying the recording is going on.

If gif is not possible then any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I know it is an old post, but what did you end up using?